# relation between inclusion and embedding

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are two Banach spaces, now we have that $X$ is included in $Y$, in the sense that $\forall a\in X$, we have $a\in Y$. Then can we get that $X$ is embedded in $Y$, namely, $\forall b\in Y, \Vert b \Vert_Y \le C\cdot \Vert b \Vert_X$?

I think there is no problem for the statement of this question by Nate Eldredge.

Comment: Is there a technical definition of 'embedding' in the context of Banach spaces?

Comment: I don't know if this is common place, but I generally consider 'inclusion' as in set relations, and 'embedding' being a continuous inclusion (that $\|u\|_Y \leq C\|u\|_X$ for some fixed constant $C$). 

Comment: (But looking at Wikipedia, I may be the only one...)

Comment: This question is not well posed, so I vote to close.

Comment: sorry, the definition is just what Wilie Wong said.

Comment: I would have gone for "inclusion" meaning "continuous injection" and "embedding" meaning "isometric injection".  "Embedding" for me carries the overtone that all the structure on the sub-object is inherited from the ambient one.  I agree with Bill that it is not well-posed.

Comment: @Shaoming: perhaps what you want to ask is: if a map $i : X \to Y$ (thought of as "inclusion") is injective, must it be continuous?  The answer is no; indeed, with the axiom of choice, one can show there exists a bijective linear map of $X$ to itself which is not continuous.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey and others: It is common in the literature of this field to use the term "embedding" for "continuous injection", instead of the perhaps more logical meaning of "homeomorphism onto its image".  Indeed, one often talks about one Banach space being "densely embedded" into another, which would be absurd under the latter sense.  I am not sure where this usage originated; it is perhaps unfortunate but it is standard now.

Comment: I wish the question were enlarged with definitions of the terms!

Comment: The new version of this question is still ill-defined. What does one mean by ``if $a\in X$ then $a\in Y$? This does not make sense without first embedding $X$ and $Y$ into some common set.

Comment: I guess you are working with function spaces and find someone deduce bouondedness of operators in this way. Roughly, for function spaces defined by integral, this is always true (consider pointwise convergent subsequences and apply closed graph theorem).

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion of $L^\infty([0,1]$ in $L^2([0,1])$ is certainly continuous, i.e., convergence in the essential sup norm implies $L^2$ convergence, but the reverse is false. So if I understand what you are asking then I guess the answer is "no".

Comment: but I think we have that, L^(inf) is embedded in L^2,
sorry for not using language of Latex

Comment: In customary terminology, an injective map is called an immersion if it is continuous, but it is only called an embedding if it is bi-continuous. 